# InteropBitmap collection to single Image

Tags: c#, wpf, interopbitmapimage

I'm using a list of InteropBitmap in order to display a set of image frames within Image control which is customized with a datatemplate.

What I'm lookin for is to export set of images in a single image, however what I get is a bad/partial image with wrong colors.

The following is the code snippet I'm using to convert set of InteropBitmap in a single image:

```
 var firstInterop = this.InteropBitmapList[0]; // Get info from first frame, all other one are the same format.

  int width = firstInterop .PixelWidth;
            int height = firstInterop.PixelHeight;
            int bpp = firstInterop Format.BitsPerPixel;

            int stride = width * (bpp / 8);
            int count = this.InteropBitmapList.Count;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[stride * height * count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var wb = this.InteropBitmapList[i];
                wb.CopyPixels(buffer, stride, width * height * i);
            }
```

Finally, I use buffer array to achieve my jpeg image through GDI+ or else wpf instruments. Unfortunately, both the way doesn't work as I expected.

Is there something to wrong in my code?

**@@EDIT**
Well, thanks to Clemens answers, now I'm able to obtain a correct image, except only for its color (all colors are altered). 
The issue is true only when I try to create an Image through GDI+, instead, if I use something of WPF susch as JpegBitmapEncoder all works fine.

The following code snippet allow me to achieve the right image:

```
byte[] buffer = MyFunc.GetBuffer();
// ...
    var bitmap = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 300, 300,
       System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, buffer, stride);
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("example.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

            encoder.QualityLevel = 100;

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
            encoder.Save(stream);
```

Instead, the following code return me an image with wrong colors (the red become blue and so on)

```
byte[] buffer = MyFunc.GetBuffer(); 
// ...
IntPtr unmanagedPointer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, unmanagedPointer, buffer.Length);

System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb (the equivalent of WPF format..)

System.Drawing.Image myImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height, stride, format, unmanagedPointer);

myImg.Save("example.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I haven't idea why it doesn't work when I use System.Drawing classes.

Comment: Shouldn't the offset in CopyPixels be `stride * height * i`?

Comment: And stride should better be calculated as `width * (bpp + 7) / 8`, just in case `bpp` is not an integer multiple of 8.

Comment: You are right. Now, my image seems uniform, but its colors are not correct. My original frame contains colors like red, orange and black. After exporting image appear with color blue..

Comment: You have to use the right bitmap format during creation of the result image. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.aspx) for possible formats.

Comment: I think format is correct. My original frames come from PixelFormat = Rgb24. Since I'm using GDI+ to create a single image, when I export my image, I convert that System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat to equivalent System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb...

Comment: And now you expect me to guess what else *exactly* you did?

Comment: If you see the right image, but with just wrong colors, it's very likely a problem with the format.

Comment: `Format24bppRgb` *is not* the equivalent of `Bgr24`. The one is R-G-B, the other B-G-R. That's why red and blue are interchanged.

Comment: Ok, so, how can I achieve the right color? Is there some solution?

Comment: Just go through the buffer and swap each pixel's red and blue byte, or don't use GDI. Or try to get the InteropBitmaps in a format supported by GDI in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57868/discussion-between-bit-and-clemens).

Comment: I'd like swap blue byte with red byte. Could you give me an example about it?

Comment: Well, you loop over your buffer with an index variable (say `i`) that you increment by 3 in each loop cycle. In each loop cycle you exchange the buffer values at positions `i` and `i+2`. This is very basic programming knowledge.

Comment: Excuse me. It'm my error. WPF format is Rgb24. I've just edit again my code snippet, so, again, I haven't idea why my colors are Exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the calculation of the buffer offset for the `i`th image. Instead of `width * height * i` it has to calculated as `stride * height * i`:

```
wb.CopyPixels(buffer, stride, stride * height * i);
```

In order to also support bits-per-pixel values that are not an integer multiples of `8`, you should calculate the stride like this:

```
int stride = (width * bpp + 7) / 8;
```

Comment: @bit This post clearly answers your question "is there something wrong in my code?". If you have another problem, ask another question, or edit this one and be more specific.

Comment: Yeah, but from your current question it is impossible to say why.

Comment: Please, see my @@EDIT on original question.